# Creating Async WCF operations in WCF +MVVM

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm-light

I am trying to implement MVVM for my WPF application. I have WCF services for which I want to create a data Model. My WCF does not implement callbacks.
I am having issues creating a Model for my Async WCF services.

Please provide me some sample on how to generate a function for a Asyn wcf service.
Suppose I have a WCF operation GetOrderDetails(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
Then how will I go about creating a Model function using the GetOrderDetailsCompleted and GetOrderDetailsAsync

Comment: The Async aspect in this case is purely a client side thing. It's not about the service supporting async but rather the client making the call asynchronously. Does your client proxy not provide you with async methods?

Comment: I understand that async is client side thing. The proxy does provide me with Async operations. But I wish to implement MVVM. And wish to create a Model for the services on the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is a purely client-side WCF issue, and is handled by the service utility code generator.

When you 'Add Service Reference...' you are able to instruct the service utility to create asynchronous operations.

- 'Add Service Reference...'
- Click 'Advanced...'
- In the Client section at the top, check the 'Generate asynchronous operations' box

The service operations will be created with asynchronous methods like `OperationNameAsync()`, and with additional events like `OperationNameCompleted`.  For samples on how to call the service asynchronously, check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx).

Comment: I have the Async operations generated when I add the Service reference. I am not asking on how to generate the Async operations for the Service added. But how to use these in a MVVM pattern?

Comment: Ok then you are done.  The MSDN link I provided explains how to use the async operations.